# Use Selenium WebDriver to make assertion on JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm testing a webpage with Selenium WebDrive and want to make an assertion on a JavaScript file but not sure how.

I want to assert that `servers` (an array) is of length 2.

My JavaScript file `config.js` contains the following array I wish to assert is present:

```
var location = location || {};
location.Config = {
    servers: [
        {name: "a"}, 
        {name: "b"}
   ]
}
```

My first attempt was to use `className` but didn't do the trick:

```
Assert.assertThat(webDriver
        .findElement(className("config.js"))
        .getAttribute("servers")
        .length(), 
    Matchers.is(2));
```

Comment: Is the file "config.js" a resource of the page?

Comment: The "config.js" file is within the site being tested and the webdriver has a handle into the site. I hope I've not misunderstood your question

Comment: What do you get if you execute "location.Config.servers[0].name" is the console of the browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success!

Passing the browser a JavaScript command to run and capturing its result has done the trick.

```
long servers = (long) ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return location.Config.servers.length");

Assert.assertThat(servers, Matchers.greaterThan((long) 0));
```